# is there cache in ubuntu when run command?

Tags: caching, path, sh, sudo

I tried to running command docker in ubuntu 14:04(LTS).

---

It locates in /usr/bin
When I type "docker" in bash shell then error come up.

```
no such file or directory in /usr/local/bin/docker
```

I logged in root account.
After I type "sudo docker" then it execute normally.

Since I typed "sudo docker", just "docker" command excutes normally.

What's happening?

Is there caching system when running program by $PATH?

Thank you! Have a nice day :)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables

Comment: This question is about using/configuring software rather than programming and it is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). [su] or [unix.se] would be a more appropriate site for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most shells implement a lookup cache to remember where a command is found after performing path lookup. This cache can typically be viewed and/or manipulated with a `hash` command; consult your shell's man page for details.